# Mongoose not defined error

Tags: mongoose, undefined

I have just started with apis in node, I got stucked with an error. I am getting error "site can't be reached" when I try to access "http://localhost:3000/". Nodemon error is also attached with this post.

### Here is app.js

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/arys');

 Employee=require('./models/employee');
//connect to mongoose
var db=mongoose.connection;

app.get('/',function(req,res){

    res.send('Use API endpointsdsfs');
});

app.get('/api/employees',function(req,res){

    Employee.getGenres((err, employees) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(emplyees);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on Port 3000');
```

---

### Here is models/employee.js

```
const mongooose=require('mongoose');



//Employee Schema

const employeeSchema=mongoose.Schema({

   name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
   },
   email:{
   type:String,
   required:true

   }
});

const Employee=module.exports=mongoose.model('Employee',employeeSchema);


//get Employees
module.exports.getEmployees= (callback, limit) =>
{

Employees.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt3jm.jpg)

Comment: **res.json(emplyees)** replace it with **res.json(employees)**

Comment: Thanks so much to correct this mistake,but that did not solved the issue that I mentioned above.

Comment: I think I found the issue, I misspelled the word mongoose with "mongooose".